# Really long query

Tags: python, django, django-models

How do u do long query? Is there way to optimize it?
I would do complicated and long query:

```
all_accepted_parts = acceptedFragment.objects.filter(fragmentID = fragment.objects.filter(categories = fragmentCategory.objects.filter(id=1)))
```

but it doesn't work, i get:

```
Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

I will be thankful for any hint how i could optimize it or solve of course too - more thankful :)

Comment: Of course, all model's filelds are correct

Comment: Your main issue is likely that filter() returns a QuerySet, which is effectively a list of objects. Try "categories__in=fragmentCategory... etc". A nested query like this is almost never necessary if your models are correctly related. If you can post the model definitions themselves, we can help you optimize the query.

Comment: @Jarret Hardie, maybe you should make that an answer.

Comment: There is no reasonable way to make sense of this without the Models. How would you render this Django ORM request in English? "Give me all the acceptedFragments that have a fragmentID that matches a fragment that has a category that matches a/the fragmentCategory(ies) that have an id of 1"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's not working, you can't optimize it.  First make it work.

At first glance, it seems that you have really mixed concepts about fields, relationships and equality/membership.  First go thought the docs, and build your query piece by piece on the python shell (likely from the inside out).

Just a shot in the dark:

```
all_accepted_parts = acceptedFragment.objects.filter(fragment__in = fragment.objects.filter(categories = fragmentCategory.objects.get(id=1)))
```

or maybe:

```
all_accepted_parts = acceptedFragment.objects.filter(fragment__in = fragment.objects.filter(categories = 1))
```

Answer (score 4):

As others have said, we really need the models, and some explanation of what you're actually trying to achieve.

But it looks like you want to do a related table lookup. Rather than getting all the related objects in a separate nested query, you should use Django's related model syntax to do the join within your query.

Something like:

```
acceptedFragment.objects.filter(fragment__categories__id = 1)
```